# Solaris bash script / search and append field to end of line in /etc/group

Tags: bash, sed, solaris, awk

I need a bash script that will modify /etc/group to append and delete NIS users to specific local groups on a Solaris 10u8 system. Preferable one or two functions with uid and groupname as varibles.

inputfile before adding a user myuser to groupbbb in file /etc/group

```
...
groupaaa::98000:
groupbbb::98001:hisuser   
groupccc::98003:
...
```

outputfile

```
...
groupaaa::98000:
groupbbb::98001:hisuser,myuser
groupccc::98003:
```

...
The function should check if user is aleady part of the local group and exit

Should I use sed or nawk or something else. Anyone have a nice oneliner :-)

In linux there is gpasswd but i havent found  a corresponding command in Solaris. The user are not local on the system but NIS users so usermod will not work I think!

Greatful for any pointers!

/Smedis

Answer (score 0):

Call this function:

```
gradd () { local group=$1 user=$2; sed "/^${group}:/{/\<${user}\>/! s/$/,${user}/}' /etc/group; }
```

like this:

```
gradd groupbbb myuser > /tmp/newgroups && mv /tmp/newgroups /etc/group
```

The file redirection and renaming could be moved inside the function:

```
gradd () { local group=$1 user=$2; sed "/^${group}:/{/\<${user}\>/! s/$/,${user}/}' /etc/group  > /tmp/newgroups && mv /tmp/newgroups /etc/group; }
```

then the call would be:

```
gradd groupbbb myuser
```

Comment: Hi!

Many thanks, will check this out asap!

/Smedis

Comment: sed -i will edit a file in place.

Comment: @kmarsh: It's not available on Solaris.

Comment: OK, but if he is using Bash, chances are good that he has the rest of the Gnu tools installed.

Comment: I have Gnu tools installed :-) I'm had to switch to another projct but I'will report back! /Smedis